# Erlang snmp MIB. Two mibs have the same name object

Tags: erlang, snmp, asn.1, mib

I have two MIB files contain two object with the same name (myentry). 
I can't load both for agent and I get error:

1> snmpa:load_mibs(snmp_master_agent, ["MY-MIB-1", "MY-MIB-2"]).

{error,{'load aborted at', "/home/artem/MY-MIB-1", {'mibentry already defined', myentry}}}

Unfortunately I can't provide MIB files. But they are valid anyway.

Is there way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Without the object tree it's rather hard to give any advice. But provided the object hang under different branches in the tree there should not be a problem.
Have a look at the otp_mibs and os_mon application for a decent reference setup.